# Timeline examples or learning resources for audio levelling of live event dialogue and audience reactions ? (e.g. stand-up comedy)

Tags: levels, sound-editing, production-audio, live-performance, comedy

For best audio quality from a live audience event, complete with audience reactions (laughter, cheering etc.) I understand that it is necessary to perform audio levelling manually, via clip gain points/nodes/keyframes/envelopes. I realise that automation tools (like RX) can help, but here I am specifically interested in the "hand-tailored" approach.

Although I have some years of experience in doing this, I have always worked alone, and I have always wondered how my approach compares to that of others, indeed whether it could be improved in quality and/or productivity (eg keyframe density). To me this kind of work seems like a fine art, but despite much web (including video) searching I have never found any examples going into detail on real-life timelines with envelope-based levelling, shaping the audience reactions and presenter comebacks so that they sounds realistic etc. Any pointers/tips ?

Comment: I don't have any examples, but if I were to be doing this type of task by hand, I'd be dragging a fader on an as-live pass, with automation, then going back through to tweak up by hand. I'd also have a comp on it to level things up a bit. I'd be doing this in Cubase/Nuendo etc as a sound stage with ancillary video playback, not in a video editor.

Answer (score 1):

**I have just found a broadly relevant example** - though film-set based (hence lacking audience reaction elements) - in one part (as per the start-time in the link) of the following Youtube presentation: [Tutorial: Dialogue Signal Processing with Matt Yocum](https://youtu.be/AZxeprFnUjI?si=QHycOKrARhWrat0e&t=421).

Based on this (admittedly singular) example, *it appears to be reasonable practice to have as many as one or two level changes per word* (e.g. for particularly loud syllables).  At least when such a degree of work is justified.

This pattern is consistent with my own clip-gain/envelope/keyframe -based manual levelling practice.

I had (for a long time) been nagged by uncertainty (in my work-isolation) about whether or not my levelling practice had been over-done (excessive keyframe/node densities).  It seems not.  Consequently this particular uncertainty will nag me no more!

Possibly this (trivial but vital) insight will likewise reassure others in a similar position.

Hopefully I will eventually locate one or more further publicly available examples, this time *including* the use of levelling edit techniques specific to audience reaction.  If/when this happens, I will link to it via a further comment to this comment-thread.